# How to handle this story

Tags: agile, agile-project-management, agile-processes

I am not sure when you would break story into stories or into tasks.

Let's say  you have a story that talks about bringing down a service, and to do that you have to analyze and depreciate 5 api where each one takes one week

How would you do that ?

1) break story into 5 stories and this way every story is less than a sprint and can be owned by someone (but cant be demoed)

2) break a story into tasks but then multiple people is working on a single story and one story is lasting more than sprint

Other?
Thank you

Comment: I would point out that you aren't talking about user stories, but rather just generic backlog items. Assuming that depricating any of them delivers value, then each one delivers some value, so it makes reasonable sense to split them up if needed and if that's reasonable to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let's say you have a story that talks about bringing down a service

Why are you doing that? Who is going to benefit from it?

That information will help you to create the story associated with the work item.

As a [person that benefits from this work] I want the service brought down so that [reason]

Now, once you have defined the user story you can then add sub-tasks to it that describe how the work will be done. e.g.

> Sub-task1 = deprecate API X
>
> Sub-task2 = deprecate API Y

Comment: But then that means the story is not owned by a single developer and more importantly is not done in a sprint. Shouldnt having thr story reaching to done done , be the goal ?

Comment: Yes, it is definitely preferable to have a story that can comfortably fit in a sprint. Once you have defined the story, have a think about possible ways to break it down into smaller stories. This can be a challenge, but the skill of breaking down large stories is worth having. There are lots of resources on internet that will offer guidance on how to break stories down. Also, in agile work is typically owned by teams rather than by individuals. Several developers may work on the same story at the same time.

Comment: I see then why not make the depcrications subtasks thatbyou have above as stories ?

Comment: A user story is something that delivers user value. It is written in the language of the user so that non-technical people can understand why you are building this requirement. Sub-tasks are technical activities that contribute towards a story. They can be written in a technical language as they only need to be understood by technical people. The reason we do this is that we want the work we are doing to be understood by non-technical people outside of the team. The sub-tasks have to be technical as they explain to the team how to build the story.

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/16739/what-is-the-weighting-difference-between-epic-story-task/16743#16743

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, the so-called story should be an epic. The epic should be split in multiple stories, each one tackling the decommissioning of a different service.

It is also equally important to split the stories into sub-tasks because you will most probably identify "hidden flaws". It will also allow you to bring more transparency in the process of completing the story. If the stories are similar from the tasking perspective, you can define the first one as a template for the other ones.

You can view this topic from a different perspective: your purpose is to remove some services that hinder your progress. After you put down one service, you are closer to the desired outcome of taking all the services down. And of course, after each decommissioned server you bring more value for you, your team, or the customer.